# asp.net mvc adding custom column to identity role table

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4

This is how I add new column to Identity role table

```
 public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    public ApplicationRole() : base() { }
    public ApplicationRole(string name, long customId) : base(name)
    {
        this.CustomId= customId;
    }
    public virtual long CustomId{ get; set; }
}
```

In dbContext , I added

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().ToTable("AspNetRoles");
```

using this , new column `CustomId` is added successfully to `AspNetRoles` table using migration .
But when I have to call role table like

```
private readonly IdentityDbContext db_Identity;
..
..
 db_Identity.Roles.Select(x=>x.CustomId)
```

I can't find newly added column `CustomId` here .
Is there any step I missed ?

**Update**

With @Chirs's answer , I can get `CoustomId` , but when I run , I got this error

```
Cannot create a DbSet for 'IdentityRole' because this type is not included in the model for the context
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using custom Identity models, you also need to inherit from one of the generic `IdentityDbContext` classes and specify your custom type in the appropriate type param. In this case, you just need something like:

```
public class MyDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string>
```

Then use your custom context class:

```
private readonly MyDbContext db_Identity;
```

Comment: that's really help , additionally , please explain me why `TKey` is leave as `string` , when should we define for it ? :)

Comment: And I got this error when I run `Cannot create a DbSet for 'IdentityRole' because this type is not included in the model for the context`